# Historic landing time for flight arriving at Gatwick from Lanzarote on 16th January 2023 at LGW

Tags: legal, online-resources, airlines, compensation, tui

Can anyone help with finding out the landing time of a flight from Lanzarote (ACE) landing at Gatwick LGW.  TOM4141 on January 16th 2023? Many thanks